# Testng test are ignored after upgrading to Sprint Boot 3 and maven-surefire-plugin 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have an application that was executing TestNG tests perfectly with maven, for example, when using a `mvn clean install` command.

Currently I have updated the application to start using Spring Boot 3.1.0, and now the tests are completely ignored. No tests are executed.

I am using a classic `testng.xml` file defined on the `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

All solutions I have found are related about the java classes ending on `*Test.java` but this is not applied as I am using the testng suite file. And before the update, the tests are working fine.

What has been changed into Spring Boot 3 to skip my tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the "issue". Seems that the new versions of `maven-surefire-plugin` [needs to include](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) a `surefire-testng` extra plugin for executing it:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

After including the dependency on the plugin, now is working fine.

Comment: That should not be neccessary because if you have correctly defined a dependency to testng this will be done by surefire-plugin automatically... that looks like an issue in your pom file... I assume you might be using junit-jupiter in general in your project?

Comment: No, I am not using it. Unless is included by `spring-boot-starter-test`.

Comment: In any case, if I remove the dependency inside the plugin, the tests are ignored again.

Comment: Than you have defined more than one unit test framework please show the full pom files etc. because by default spring boot used junit-jupiter and not TestNG... I would ask why do you use TestNG instead of JUnit Jupiter?

Comment: I am feel comfortable with TestNG and I am using it for more than 10 years now. The pom related to this contain, `org.testng`dependency, `maven-surefire-plugin`, and `spring-boot-starter-test`. If you want more details, you have a project [here](https://github.com/softwaremagico/KendoTournamentManager/tree/spring-3.0)

Comment: I've used TestNG for a long time but I've switched about 4 years ago because it offers more flexibility(extensions etc). than TestNG does. Why using the suiteFile? That can handled by default via naming conventions etc. without the need of a suite file... even in TestNG....

Comment: Suite file has some advantages that naming conventions not (listeners, etc. that I use). But I think that discussing about why testng or juniper, or why using a suitefile is outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: Listeners are not flexible enough..extensions in JUnit Jupiter are much more flexible etc. suites can be defined with JUnit Jupiter as well (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-suite-engine-example)